# Can dataGridView1 show in second Form2

Tags: c#, excel

I need guide for dataGridView.im try to do is Form1 only for show what inside excel and then proceed for form2 todo filter the data or add data or delete(modifier).thank you

[image: This form1]
[image: this form2 for modifier]

``

```
 private void b_procced_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(dataGridView1.DataSource);
        f.ShowDialog();
       }
```

```
Got error at new Form2(dataGridView1.DataSource)..
```

Comment: Thank you .. Already get the answer.my custructor got prblme.I solve like this on
Form 1 I put : new Form2(dataGridView1.DataSource); 
Form 2 Just Put (public Form2(object dataSource)
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;

this on ryt?

Comment: You need a constructor.  DO NOT USE OBJECT when you know you are passing a DATAGRIDVIEW.  Add a constructor to the Form2 with DataGridView parameter.

Comment: @jdweng thank for the tips but i already add constructor before but i keep geetings error datagridview1 on form2  cannot detect.

Comment: Here is a two form project that a wrote a number of years ago.  It may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thank you sir for the guide. yes before this im using like that 1 sir 
public string GetData()
        {
            return ";  < dgv = form2(datagridview.datasource)
        }
i got this problem when i try to call my datagridview it said no argument.so i try other one

Comment: Look at my example.  GetData would mean the form doesn't close.  Inside form 2 you need a method to return GetData.  The argument list has to be the same in form 1 and form 2. So code should be  form2.GetData(datagridview.datasource)

Comment: thank sir. yes i understand the code but when i try i keep Error Identifier expected public string getdata(dataGridView1.DataSource).Im i doing wrong in the code?

Comment: The parameter types have to match between where called and the method.  If types do not match you will get error.  Also method has to have PUBLIC.